# Removing extentions and trailing slash with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do this,
  if my url is mysite/about i want to redirect to about.php and do the same for mysite/about/ . How can i do with this htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you do any research to find a solution for this?

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^home?$  index.php 
RewriteRule  ^contact?$  contact.php 
RewriteRule  ^about?$  about.php 
RewriteRule  ^mobapper?$  mobapper.php 
RewriteRule  ^snapread?$  snapread.php  
RewriteRule  ^work?$  work.php  
#RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]                                                           ,RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]             I tried certain things like this.

Comment: Not in comments, you should post your code by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than rewrite rules you do same using `MultiViews` option by placing this line in your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.